# How to rewrite JS form submit after target="_blank" has been deprecated

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have read the new `Window.open()` api to open regular links in a new tab.

What i do not yet understand however is, how to rewrite JS form submits action while avoiding the now deprecated `target="_blank"`.

Below is my current code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
    $.extend({
        redirectPost: function(location, args)
        {
            var form = '';
            $.each( args, function( key, value ) {
                form += '<input type="hidden" name="'+key+'" value="'+value+'">';
            });
            $form = $('<form action="'+location+'" method="POST" target="_blank">'+form+'</form>');
            $form.appendTo('body');
            $form.submit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: you can change target value when you deploy on page ($("#ID").attr("target","****"))

Comment: Add an event handler for the submit event? `$form.on('submit', function(){ window.open('url', 'title') })`

Comment: Sorry to ask, but how would this change the three $form lines? Not quite sure how to integrate the attributes...